# Module (ZfcUser) could not be initialized

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

After installing ZfcBase and ZfcUser in my app I get the error message:

```
'Module (ZfcUser) could not be initialized.' in Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 140
```

I installed ZfcBase and ZfcUser in exactly the same way and location and ZfcBase loads correctly.

The relevant code in ModuleManager.php is:

```
/**
     * Load a specific module by name.
     *
     * @param    string $moduleName
     * @throws   Exception\RuntimeException
     * @triggers loadModule.resolve
     * @triggers loadModule
     * @return   mixed Module's Module class
     */
    public function loadModule($moduleName)
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedModules[$moduleName])) {
            return $this->loadedModules[$moduleName];
        }

        $event = ($this->loadFinished === false) ? clone $this->getEvent() : $this->getEvent();
        $event->setModuleName($moduleName);

        $this->loadFinished = false;

        $result = $this->getEventManager()->trigger(ModuleEvent::EVENT_LOAD_MODULE_RESOLVE, $this, $event, function ($r) {
            return (is_object($r));
        });

        $module = $result->last();

        if (!is_object($module)) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Module (%s) could not be initialized.',
                $moduleName
            ));
        }
```

How would I be able to debug this issue?

Comment: How did you install ZfcUser? I strongly suggest doing it using `composer.phar`. The ModuleManagers code is solid, the error is 100% on users side (no offense ^^). Maybe misspelled, maybe wrong path, maybe wrong load order (base first, then user)

Comment: Used composer and works now. No need to even load Base explicitly. Probably Doctrine or other dependency that I missed installing manually. I resisted to composer because it should be used on a per project basis. But now I use it for several projects where I install to a common vendor directory and all projects share the composer autoload file. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: Upvote's enough ;) You may post the final solution you did as an answer on your own and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sam in the comments above, I installed with Composer and ZfcUser works fine. No need to even load ZfcBase explicitly. It was probably Doctrine or other dependency that I missed installing manually. I initially resisted to using Composer because it should be used on a per project basis. But now I use it for several projects where I install to a common vendor directory and all projects share the same index.php, ini_autoload.php and Composer autoload.php file.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you installed ZfcUser by cloning the Github repo and creating a git submodule. I've run into issues cloning my entire application (to a new machine for example) without cloning each submodule in separately every time. I encountered the same error you did otherwise.

As others have said, use composer unless you have a good reason not to do so.